# C# Windows Forms How to edit property of something in the tabpage

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, tabcontrol

I want to edit a property "Word Wrap" in the richtextbox, which is in the tabpage. How to edit a property of this richtextbox in code?

More details:

I made two forms. **One with tab control and other things and one without borders, only with RichTextBox.** On load I added richTextBox from Form2 to empty TabPage in Form1, later I changed DockStyle of richTextBox to Fill, at the end I added this TabPage to the TabControl. And now I want to make Word Wrap button in Menu Strip, so I want to access to richTextBox of selectedTab (yes, I added "new tab" button ) and modify it's property, but I don't know how.

Comment: this.richTextBox1.WordWrap = true; // or false

Comment: @Bahrom Yup, not working. Look below, please.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you can see in the properties grid is, in some way, a [Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties) of the object instance (the properties grid is populated by examining the property members of the object

If your rich text box is called `richTextBox1` then the property in code is `richTextbox1.WordWrap`

Sometimes the properties grid has a custom editor, like the Dock property, you don't simply choose a value from a combobox, there's a dedicated editor device that has buttons (a north / south / east / west / centre button arrangement) - don't be confused by his, all it's doing is setting some normal enumeration value like Fill or Top.. it's just that Microsoft decided to build a custom editor for it

If you take a look at the auto generated code file `YourFormName.Designer.cs` you'll see all the code that the forms designer has created: if you set wordwrap in the properties grid, you'll find he relevant line of code in there, and you can copy it out if you want (handy for more complex stuff like event handlers )

In summary, just remember, the windows forms designer doesn't do anything other than write normal c# code, just like you can! Take a look at the `.Designer` file to see what I mean. If it doesn't show up in e solution explorer then just take a look in the folder on disk where all your code is..

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't it. Please, look below and read my second post

Comment: Unfortunately the extra detail you've added doesn't seem to help.. your original question was quite clear, but with this new info it seems to be that what you originally asked wasnt actually what you wanted to know. Your later revisions seem to be asking something like "how can I programmatically find the ricktextbox in a panel so I can change its word wrap setting"